# Can Embedded Service Chats be copied and pasted into HTML similar to chat button and deployment code from Live Agent

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community, liveagent

Currently, we have a Live Agent implementation that uses chat button code and deployment code which is pasted into the Html of our pages.

We are thinking of moving the current code functionality into an Embedded Service Chat. Will we be able to copy and paste the code generated from the Embedded deployment in the same manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it will be copy and paste. The only thing is that you can't necessarily easily test it using local HTML.

In order to test the embedded service:

- I have created a repository on github and added an index.html to it which contains the embedded service code.
- I am utilizing github pages to preview the page.
- I then added my github page url to Salesforce CORS.